# How to change the name of objects in Django admin?

Tags: python, django

What to do? I kept restarting my server but it still didn't work. This is the whole code snippet of my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

    class Blog(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        # publication date
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
        summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

But the names of each objects are still not changing:
[image]

Comment: Where did you put your `__str__()` method?  You need to define it in your `Blog` class model.

Comment: Hey man, I re edited my snippet so that you can see my whole code. Check it out!

Comment: In which django version you are working now?

Comment: Django 3.0.4 @PruthviBarot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the method inside the Blog Model as following:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Blog(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Hey @PremMoktan. Thanks a lot sorry I told you that it didn't work. But now I saw the problem. I haven't indented my function to have it inside the class block. hahaha. Thanks!

Comment: @ZeddrixFabian You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Your def **str**(self) is not indented inside your model class. Make the changes and it will work.

```
class modelClass(models.Model):
    #your properties
        
    #below method should be indented 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.property
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try below?

```py
class Blog(models.Model):
    ........

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```